# Не работает проверка столкновений[Unity]

Tags: unity3d

Пытаюсь сделать проверку столкновения пули и врага, который двигается по определенной траектории. В коде врага написал:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    print(collision.gameObject.name);

}
```

Box колайдеры добавил, но столкновения все равно не происходит, у пули поставил галочку на OnTrigger.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: галочку isTrigger уберите

Comment: или переопределяйте `OnTriggerEnter`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Изменил метод на:
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
  print("kkk");

 }
Но все равно столкновение не происходит

Comment: добавьте компонент RigidBody

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, без него никак? Он добавляет физику, которая мне совсем не к чему и сам этот компонент довольно требовательный

Comment: Никак. Коллайдер без RigidBody не работает.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский но ведь это не так

Comment: @StrangerintheQ для коллизии нужен хотя бы 1 RigidBody, коллайдер без RB считается статическим коллайдером/триггером, а 2 статических коллайдера чисто логически не могут столкнуться - на то они и статичные.